# Need some help/guidance on MongoDB aggregation/mapreduce queries

Tags: mongodb

I've got host scan data that I've imported into MongoDB in the following format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fd928c62c9815b36f66e68"),
    "date" : "1/1/2014",
    "scanner" : "123.9.74.172",
    "csp" : "aws",
    "ip" : "126.34.44.38",
    "port" : 445,
    "latt" : 35.685,
    "long" : 139.7514,
    "country" : "Japan",
    "continent" : "AS",
    "region" : 40,
    "city" : "Tokyo"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fd928c62c9815b36f66e69"),
    "date" : "1/1/2014",
    "scanner" : "119.9.74.172",
    "csp" : "aws",
    "ip" : "251.252.216.196",
    "port" : 135,
    "latt" : -33.86150000000001,
    "long" : 151.20549999999997,
    "country" : "Australia",
    "continent" : "OC",
    "region" : 2,
    "city" : "Sydney"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fd928c62c9815b36f66e6a"),
    "date" : "1/1/2014",
    "scanner" : "143.9.74.172",
    "csp" : "aws",
    "ip" : "154.248.219.132",
    "port" : 139,
    "latt" : 35.685,
    "long" : 139.7514,
    "country" : "Japan",
    "continent" : "AS",
    "region" : 40,
    "city" : "Tokyo"
}
```

Since I"m new to mongo, I've been looking at the aggregation framework and mapreduce to figure out how to create some queries. I can't, however, for the life of me figure out how to do things as simple as:

1. Count the distinct "ip" addresses with "port" 445 with a "date" of "1/1/2014"
2. Return the "ip" address with the most open "ports", by "date"
3. Count the distinct "ip" addresses, by "csp", for every "date" in January

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been reading and reading but the queries keep exceeding the 16MB limit. As you can see below, I have a lot of entries:

```
{
    "ns" : "brisket.my_models",
    "count" : 117715343,
    "size" : 25590813424,
    "avgObjSize" : 217.3957342502073,
    "storageSize" : 29410230112,
    "numExtents" : 33,
    "nindexes" : 1,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 3819900784,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 3819900784
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Could you add what you've tried? The queries at first glance look straightforward for the aggregation framework, although if you hit the 16mb limit, you'll need to limit the results more until MongoDB 2.6 ships.

Answer (score 0):

1) `db.my_models.distinct( "ip", { "port": "445", "date": "1/1/2014" } )`
2)

```
db.my_models.aggregate([
    { $group: 
        {
            _id: { ip: "$ip", date: "$date" },
            open_ports: { $addToSet: "$port" }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$open_ports" },
    { $group: 
        {
            _id: "$_id",
            open_ports_count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { "open_ports_count": -1 },
    { $limit: 10 }  
])
```

3) `db.my_models.distinct( "ip", { "csp": <some_value>, "date": <RegExp_for_January> } )`

At point 3 you could use Regular Expression for any day in January. You could read about JavaScript RegExp to create it.
May be I'm not understund what you want in point 2. Another query for "by date":

```
db.my_models.aggregate([
    { $match: { "date": <Your_date> } },
    { $group: 
        {
            _id: "$_id",
            open_ports: { $addToSet: "$port" }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$open_ports" },
    { $group: 
        {
            _id: "$_id",
            open_ports_count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { "open_ports_count": -1 },
    { $limit: 10 }  
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I want to start by saying that looking at the data you have presented your dates are going to be a problem for you as they appear to be strings rather than date objects. So to prefix anything in a further response, you should look into (if at all possible) getting those dates converted on *import* to be a date type or at the very least make the dates lexical.

It is true you could employ [$substr](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) operations on your current "date" values for some of the results you want to achieve, but this would not help you very much in the initial filtering that you are likely to need on large data.

[ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) style dates are lexical with a *year*, *month* and *day* format. Of course having all *month* and *day* as 2 digits as in "01". But converting to dates would be better.

The next case in all queries is that if you are hitting **100MB** then your first phase in anything you are doing should be to try and [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) the documents that you are specifically looking at. If necessary in testing then also add a [$limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) stage in order to keep the set size down.

If *$match* is really not working for you at the end of the day, the next release of MongoDB has options to work in each stage of [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/aggregate/) using temporary storage on disk. If you are evaluating / in development and not in production, then it might be worthwhile looking at the current development branch release (2.5.5) and [installing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#manage-installed-versions).

So for the following I'm going to keep in mind that dates are date types, and we are using aggregation:

For your first problem **(1)** Most importantly filter the working set, selecting between a date range (or absolute value as string) as shown:

```
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Limit if you really have to for a working set
    //{$limit: 10000 },

    // Filter with $match just the date and port needed
    {$match: 
        date: {$gte: new Date("2014-01-01"), $lt: new Date("2014-01-02")},
        port: "445"
    },

    // Group on "ip" 
    {$group: { _id: "$ip", count: {$sum: 1} } },

    // Optionally sort the results
    {$sort: { count: -1 } }

])
```

For the second problem **(2)** it is again likely that you want to break this into ranges of dates, and using the real dates or lexical strings will help in the range.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Limit if you really have to for a working set
    //{$limit: 10000 },

    // Filter with $match just the dates needed
    {$match: 
        date: {$gte: new Date("2014-01-01"), $lt: new Date("2014-01-31")},
    },

    // Moving things that can be some time of day to a whole date
    {$project:
        date: { 
            year: {$year: "$date"},
            month: {$month: "$date"},
            day: {$dayOfMonth: "$date" }  
        },
        ip: 1,
        port: 1
    },

    /* Optional for "unique" ports if required
    {$group: { _id: { date: "$date", ip: "$ip" }, ports: {$addToSet: "$port"} }},
    {$unwind: "$ports" },
    {$project: { date: "$_id.date", ip: "$_id.ip" } }
    */

    // Grouping on "date" and "ip" 
    {$group: { _id: { date: "$date", ip: "$ip" }, count: {$sum: 1} }},

    // Sort the results by date and 
    {$sort: { 
        "_id.date.year": -1, "_id.date.month": -1, "_id.date.day": -1, "count": -1 
    }},

    // Get the "first" count for each date. With nice dates
    {$group: {
        _id: {
            date: {$concat: [
                {$substr: [ "$_id.date.year", 0, 4 ] },
                "-",
                {$substr: [ "$_id.date.month", 0, 2 ] },
                "-",
                {$substr: [ "$_id.date.day", 0, 2 ] }
            ]},
            ip: "$_id.ip"
        },
        count: {$first: "$count" }
    }},

    // Optionally make the documents nicer
    {$project: { _id: 0, date: "$_id.date", ip: "$_id.ip", count: 1 } }

])
```

For the third problem **(3)** again you want to filter the dates and the relevant documents as you go in:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Limit if you really have to for a working set
    //{$limit: 10000 },

    // Filter with $match just the dates needed
    {$match: 
        date: {$gte: new Date("2014-01-01"), $lt: new Date("2014-01-31")},
    },

    // Moving things that can be some time of day to a whole date
    {$project:
        date: { 
            year: {$year: "$date"},
            month: {$month: "$date"},
            day: {$dayOfMonth: "$date" }  
        },
        ip: 1,
        csp: 1
    },

    // Get the set of "unique ip" per "date" and "csp"
    {$group: {
        _id: {
            date: {$concat: [
                {$substr: [ "$date.year", 0, 4 ] },
                "-",
                {$substr: [ "$date.month", 0, 2 ] },
                "-",
                {$substr: [ "$date.day", 0, 2 ] }
            ]},
            csp: "$csp"
        },
        ips: {$addToSet: "$ip" }
    }},

    // Unwind the *set* for the next stage
    {$unwind: "$ips" },

    // Count on the current *key*
    {$group: { _id: "$_id", count: {$sum: 1} }},

    // Clean up the documents
    {$project: { _id: 0, date: "$_id.date", csp: "$_id.csp", count: 1 } }

])
```

Hopefully the use of *$match* keeps your working set sizes under the limit, and if needed look at reducing those date ranges, combining the results in another collection and running the aggregation again over those reduced results. Even considering the upcoming features allowing disk usage, this may still be the most performant approach with very large sets.